# PHP Remove all non letters

Tags: php, regex

I have several strings that look like this:

LasklÃ©
Jones & Jon

I am trying to send them via the foursquare API to be matched, however it is failing with these characters. Is there a way to sanitise these so they only include English letters i.e. the results would be:

Lasklé
Jones Jon

As it appears using `file_get_contents` requests both with the 'Ã©' and the '&' in the URL is causing issues.

I checked how the request was sent and realised that the '&' is uneeded and is causing the issues, is it possible to remove all non Letters/Numbers from the name?

Comment: you need to `urlencode` them first

Comment: `Ã©` should be UTF8, `&` should be url encoded

Comment: use `urlencode ( $str )` to encode your URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use preg_replace() function to replace the part of string using regex

to keep only letters you can use as follow it will also remove space( add \s from expression to keep space)

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/','',$string);
```

to keep space in the string or any character to keep you can add it in []

```
 preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\s]/','',$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

What do the strings look like before you pass them? If your string looks like 'LasklÃ©' then I think you are using the wrong character set when reading the string, try using UTF-8.

If the string looks correct before you pass it on you should try [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the string first.

Comment: I used `utf8_decode` then `urlencode` which gives me:

Jones+%26%23038%3B+Sons

Then when I send the match request to foursquare along with the latitude/longitude 51.551883,-0.073798 I get no matches. However, using Chrome and sending the request as Jones+&+Sons does create a match. What is the difference between what Chrome sends and what PHP is sending?

Comment: What you are urlencoding there is Jones &#038; Sons, the & has already been converted to its htmlentity form. What you want to come out with is  Jones+%26+Sons. What does the string look like if you dump it directly after reading it (i.e. before any manipulation)? You may need to show your code here in order to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to escape (space and '-'). Good for making a custom URL

```
$string=preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\/\-]/", '', $string);
```