# IF with string read by FGETCSV

Tags: php, string, if-statement, fgetcsv

I have a problemi in using an IF statement with a string read from a file through fgetcsv command.
The file start with *Country* (**without quotes**) in the first position so I put an IF statement at the beginning of my code in order to verify that the file is correct.
The IF statement is:

```
if ($data[0]=="Country") {
…
} else { 
print $data[0] 
}
```

The IF statement fails but... on the screen I see the word *Country*.
It means that the fgetcsv works well, but there are problems on string comparison.
Can anyone tell me why the IF statement fails?

Thanks in advance for any help

giorgio

Comment: Check if it's really displaying just the characters `Country` or if there could be any whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc) in what it displays.... use `var_dump($data[0]);` instead of `print $data[0];`

Comment: I tried putting quotes before and after $data[0]: no spaces are present. I tried also with htmlentities to verify if HTML special characters are present but it seems like $data[0] contains just the word Country

Comment: have u properly used ; for your code like u left in your else stmt

Comment: Try using var_dump() as I suggested, and show us the output from that

Comment: Sorry Mark, I missed your tip.

Comment: string(10) "Country"

Data[0]=

Comment: The code is        

echo "Data[0]=".var_dump($data[0])"     

but on the screen I see 
     
string(10) "Country"      

"Data[0]="

Comment: So it's a 10-character string; and `Country` is only 7 characters, so there's three invisible (whitespace) characters in the string.... try doing `if (trim($data[0])=="Country")`

Comment: already tried with trim()

Comment: Try using a regex, just to check if it is invisible characters causing the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22657781/608312

Comment: My money is on it being a BOM.

Comment: Use something like a [string to hex convertor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674834/php-convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string) to dump your $data[0] string as hex ASCII values so that we can see exactly what you're getting

Comment: Thanks to all!!!
It's a BOM, bin2hex($data[0]) reports "efbbbf436f756e747279" and EFBBBF is the BOM for UTF-8.
I never stop learning :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing like this:

```
if (strtolower(trim($data[0])) == 'country') {
  echo 'found';
} else { 
  print $data[0] 
}
```